# VMWare Pro 12 on 16.04 with 4.13.0-26-generic

Tags: 16.04, vmware-workstation

Trying to get VMW Pro 12 to run 16.01 with 4.13.0-26-generic kernel.

Keep getting "Failed to build vmnet. Failed to execute the build command."

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I had the same issue.  I ended up upgrading to VMWare 14.  No matter what I tried, I could not get the vmnet to build so I upgraded.

Comment: Once I got working, following a tutorial that I cannot find again. It was about reaching the `/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source` directory, unpacking `vmnet.tar` and `vmmon.tar` archives, change a line or two of code in the files inside, and repacking it both. Now I'm using VMWare 14 and I've got no problems at all. If I find the link to the tutorial, I'll post it here!

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

```
cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source
tar -xf vmmon.tar
nano vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c
```

Search and replace all the instances of `get_user_pages` with `get_user_page_remote`

```
tar -cf vmmon.tar vmmon-only
```

Let's edit `vmnet.tar`

```
tar -xf vmnet.tar
nano vmnet-only/linux/hostif.c
```

Search and replace all the instances of `get_user_pages` with `get_user_page_remote`

```
tar -cf vmnet.tar vmnet-only
```

Now, you should be able to compile the modules!

Comment: Thanks a ton for the response... Nothing seems to be working. Going to go with the 14 eval and if that works just suck it up and buy the upgrade.